# How to get the state from the ngrx store without reselect library?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

How to get the state from the **ngrx store** without using the `reselect createSelector` and [store.select](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/containers/collection-page.ts) method in this [example](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/reducers/index.ts)?

`export const getBookCollection = createSelector(getBookEntities, getCollectionBookIds, (entities, ids) => {
  return ids.map(id => entities[id]);
});`

`constructor(store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    this.books$ = store.select(fromRoot.getBookCollection);
}`

Comment: why wouldn't you want to use store.select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only the store.select you could do:

```
export const getBooksCollection = (state: State) => {
    const ids = state.collection.ids;
    const entities = state.books.entities;
    return ids.map(id => entities[id]);
}

constructor(store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    this.books$ = store.select(fromRoot.getBookCollection);
}
```